# GLSL: binding Shader Storage Buffer Object

Tags: binding, glsl

I'm binding a Shader Storage Buffer Object (SSBO) and use in the Fragment Shader. The bindings are fine, the buffer block is a multiple of vec4(4B) blocks as required by the specifications. However, the following code has an unexpected behavior. The variable 'datapoint' has the correct 'a' value, but the 'b,c,d' values are garbage.

I'm using an Nvidia Quadro K5000 with driver version 340.52.

```
struct data
{
    int a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float d;
};

// the same location '0' is used on the host
layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer MyBuffer 
{
    data mydata[];
}

data datapoint;

void main()
{
    ...

    datapoint = mydata[some_index]; // some_index is withing range

    ...
}
```

Comment: You could try to add a qualifier to the buffer, e.g., readonly or coherent, and see if that helps

Comment: also, as far as i understood, you have to give a name to your MyBuffer, and access it via name.mydata[]

Comment: The problem seems to be with the = operator. Accessing the data by 'mydata[some_index].c' is okay to do so. However, copying it to another instance of the struct only copies the first element of the struct. The problem could be specific to NVidia's GLSL compiler.